# Apply a function to all columns of data frame which returns a list

Tags: r, dplyr, transformation

I have a data set that contains skewed data.

```
d = data.frame(x = sample(1:15, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:15),
               y = sample(1:20, size = 50, replace = TRUE, prob = 20:1))
```

I want to apply a Johnson transformation to every column. I tried it with the apply function.

```
library(jtrans)
```

x = apply(d, 2, jtrans)

However, since the transformed values are in a list (i.e. x$x$transformed or x$y$transformed) I don´t know how to apply this to the data frame?

Comment: RE.Johnson doesn't seem to be working depending on the `d` created.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function and extract the transformed values from the resulting object.

```r
library(jtrans)
#> Warning: package 'jtrans' was built under R version 3.4.4

set.seed(1)

d = data.frame(x = sample(1:15, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:15),
               y = sample(1:20, size = 50, replace = TRUE, prob = 20:1))

new_d <- sapply(d, function(x) jtrans(x)$transformed)

head(new_d)
#>               x           y
#> [1,]  0.8277242  0.55000000
#> [2,]  0.4400000 -0.06683963
#> [3,] -0.1764075 -0.55000000
#> [4,] -1.3760105  1.79402536
#> [5,]  1.3200000  0.55000000
#> [6,] -1.3760105 -0.55000000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>